# Targeting a specific part of an associative (one-demonsional) array?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, key, associative

I want to try to swap the first and last index's of this array:

```
 <?php
 $their_name = array(
      'Jim'   => 'dad', 
      'Josh'  => 'son', 
      'Jamie' => 'mom', 
      'Jane'  => 'daughter', 
      'Jill'  => 'daughter'
 );
 ?>
```

So that it will look like this:

```
 <?php
 $their_name = array(
      'Jill'   => 'dad', 
      'Josh'  => 'son', 
      'Jamie' => 'mom', 
      'Jane'  => 'daughter', 
      'Jim'  => 'daughter'
 );
 ?>
```

I did something similar last night with an array using these:

```
$temp                   = $user_name[0];     
$user_name[0]           = end($user_name);    
$count                  = count($user_name);  
$user_name[$count-1]    = $temp;             
return $user_name;
```

I'm assuming that these methodology will be similar. However, $their_name[0] returns 'J'.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you mean by "target specific portions"?

Comment: What language? It looks like PHP, but you should tag it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a potential solution to your specific problem...

```
$their_name = array(
  'Jim'   => 'dad', 
  'Josh'  => 'son', 
  'Jamie' => 'mom', 
  'Jane'  => 'daughter', 
  'Jill'  => 'daughter'
);
// rewind array pointer to first element
reset($their_name);
// get key name
$firstKey = key($their_name);
// get value and remove from array
$firstValue = array_shift($their_name);

// advance pointer to last element 
end($their_name);
// get key name
$lastKey = key($their_name);
// get value and remove from array
$lastValue = array_pop($their_name);

// first element using last key and first value
$firstElement = array($lastKey => $firstValue);
// last element using first key and last value
$lastElement = array($firstKey => $lastValue);

// add them to the remaining elements 
$their_name = $firstElement + $their_name + $lastElement;

var_dump($their_name);
// Result:
array(5) {
    ["Jill"]=>
    string(3) "dad"
    ["Josh"]=>
    string(3) "son"
    ["Jamie"]=>
    string(3) "mom"
    ["Jane"]=>
    string(8) "daughter"
    ["Jim"]=>
    string(8) "daughter"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems incredibly basic, but is this what you're asking about:

```
echo $their_name['Jane'];

$their_name['Josh'] = 'son-in-law';
```

Comment: That is indeed basic, but my goal is going a bit further with it. I want to make the first name (Jim) and the last (Jill) switch places. I just needed to get the basics, so that I can try to target it more precisely.

Once I do that, I will then try to make it repeatable, so that if a new name is added, say 'Jackie', it will swap that with 'Jim' and Jill will be in it's rightful place.

Comment: I tried using end($their_name), which resulted in 'daughter.' I didn't expect that.

Comment: Why didn't you expect that? It's the last value in the array, isn't it? Anyway, it sounds like `array_splice()` is the function you're looking for, to put elements in a specific place in an array.

Comment: It's still not clear what your real goal is. What criteria are you using for the order of elements, i.e. what makes a certain place Jill's "rightful place"? Please update your question with more details, right now it's so vague as to be unanswerable.